# Pass value of JQuery datepicker to control action

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm new to ASP and JQuery. I need to pass my datepicker value to Controller action.
So I'v created datepicker using JQuery UI:

```
<input class="date-picker" />
```

And script for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker();
    })
</script>
```

Also I have a controller method:

```
public ActionResult LoadData(string dateFrom)
{
    // Here I'm loading data and return partialView
}
```

So this is how I'm trying to pass value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var url = '@Url.Action("LoadData", "Home")';
        $('#Load').click(function() {
          var from = $('#date-picker').val();
          $('#result').load(url, { from: from });
        })
</script>
```

So if I pass I simple string thats works, but if I'm try to pass dateOicker value I'v got null in LoadData method.

What's wrong?

Comment: use `$('.date-picker').val();`

Comment: give your input control a id "date-picker".

Comment: And the method should be `public ActionResult LoadData(DateTime dateFrom)` - not `string`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `$('.date-picker').val();`
2. Since it is class

Comment: its better to always add ID and then access the data from it